# Is $\det(c I_n - A^T) = \det(c I_n - A)$? How to prove it?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

**Problem:** Are the following assertions true or false? Prove or give a counterexample:

1) If $A$ is an $(n \times n)$-matrix, then for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $\det(c I_n - A) = c^n - \det(A)$.

2) If $A$ is an $(n \times n)$-matrix, then for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $\det(c I_n - A^T) = \det(c I_n - A)$.

**Attempt:**
1) This is false. Let $c I_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$. Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$. Then \begin{align*} \det(c I_2 - A) = \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -2 & -1 \end{pmatrix} = -1. \end{align*} But \begin{align*} c^2 - \det(A) = 2^2 - 3 = 1. \end{align*}

2) For the second assertion, I think this is true. I tried to find a counter example, but couldn't. So how can I prove it?

Comment: 2) $\det(A) = \det(A^{T})$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (2), note that
$$cI_n-A^T = (cI_n)^T-A^T = (cI_n-A)^T,$$
and then that $\det A = \det A^T$ for any $A$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $\det(M) = \det(M^T)$ for any square matrix $M$.

---

**Solution**: (after comment exchange below)

Let $M = cI_n - A$.

Note that $M^T = cI_n^T - A^T = cI_n - A^T$.

Then, from the hint, you get $\det(cI_n - A) = \det(cI_n - A^T)$

Comment: I know this. But this doesn't prove it. I cannot deduce from this that $\det(c I_n - A^T) = \det(c I_n - A)$, can I?

Comment: @Kamil Why not?

Comment: That would only be possible if $\det(c I_n - A^T) = \det(c I_n) - \det(A^T)$, and hence $\det(c I_n) - \det(A) = \det(c I_n - A)$. But determinantmap is not linear.

Comment: What makes you think that this is the "only way"?

Comment: @Kamil If $M=cI_n-A$, what is $M^T$?

Comment: Someone down-voted me? For a complete and correct answer, after having provided a hint? Wow... that's harsh.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It is useful to note that
$$
cI_n - A^T = [cI_n - A]^T
$$